# Unable to connect to ldap using python ldap3 module

Tags: python, ldap, openldap, python-ldap, ldap3

I am using Online LDAP Test Server(https://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/)

I am trying to connect to it using python ldap3 module.

This is my code:

```
import ldap3
user = 'riemann'
password = 'password'
server = ldap3.Server('ldap.forumsys.com', port=389)
connection = ldap3.Connection(server, user=user, password=password)
connection.bind()
conn = connection.search(search_base='ou=mathematicians,dc=example,dc=com', search_filter='(&(objectClass=user)(userPrincipalName='+user+'))', attributes='*')

print conn
```

When I check the conn it is **False**.

Can someone help me in getting the connection
Thanks in advance

Comment: The following are [30 code examples](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/107944/ldap3) for showing how to use `ldap3` and [Tutorial: Introduction to ldap3](https://ldap3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial_intro.html#tutorial-introduction-to-ldap3).

Answer (score 1):

if you change `user='riemann'` to `user='uid=riemann,dc=example,dc=com'` you'll get a connection

for more information check the docs: http://ldap3.readthedocs.io/bind.html#simple-bind